# Add 1 day to salesforce date field inside validation rule

Tags: apex, formula, validation-rule

Good day everyone. I am trying to to add one day to my date field inside a validation rule. What is the exact way to do it ? For now, I try this syntax:

```
IF(DATE(YEAR(asph_End_date__c),MONTH(End_date__c),(DAY(asph_End_date__c) + 1))  < Start_date__c  ,true,false)
```

The problem with this is that, It will give an error if my end date falls on the last day of the month. What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a day is easy:

```
Today()+1
```

My formula for adding a month is much more complex.